# subSetSum - powerSum JS . concatenating arrays into subset

Tags: javascript, algorithm, oop

With my very poor js knowledge, I am trying to solve the powerSum algorithm.Where I am supposed to return the count of the ways a number X can be expressed as the sum of the Nth powers of unique, natural numbers... 
I have -somehow- got to the point where I can see my subsets printed out on the console but I haven't been able to figure out how to concatenate the result of my 'subsetSum' function to my 'subsets' variable so I can return my result as an array of arrays. The only way I get to have any returning value is if I concat my subsets into a STRING. and that is not what I am expecting. Here is my code.

// returns an array with all the results of natural numbers elevated
//to the nth power <=  X

```
function powersLessThan(x,power){
  let newArr = [];
  for(var i = 1; i < x; i+=1){    
    var powered = Math.pow(i,power);
    if (powered <= x){
      newArr.push(powered);
    }else if (powered > x){
        break;
    }
  }
  return newArr;
}
```

// returns an array of all the possible combinations of numbers that sum to X

```
   function subsetsSum(numbersArr,target,partialSum){
      var sum,n,remaining;
      var subsets = [];
      partialSum = partialSum || [];
      sum = partialSum.reduce(function (a,b){
        return a +  b;
      },0);

      if (sum === target){
         return partialSum;  // this is my base case. datatype = object. Not sure why... ?? 

      }

for (var i = 0; i < numbersArr.length; i+=1){
    n = numbersArr[i];
    remaining = numbersArr.slice( i + 1);
    subsets.concat((subsetsSum(remaining,target,partialSum.concat([n]))));
  }
  return subsets;
}


console.log(subsetsSum(powersLessThan(100,2),100));  // with this my ooutput
is ' 1,9,16,25,4936,64100' instead of  => [[1,9,16,25,49],[64,36],[100]]  :/
```

The final count will be the length of the array above .. when it works..

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Just realized that my partialSum is not an actual array. It is an object and that is the reason for it to not to be able to concatenate into my subsets arr. Now, how did partialSum become an object? How can I work with it so i can get my expected array of subsets?

Comment: `console.log(Array.isArray(partialSum))` returns `true`. Keep in mind that `Array` is an object in JS so `typeof partialSum` still returns `object`.

Answer (score 0):

Change:

```
return partialSum;
```

To:

```
return [partialSum];
```

And change:

```
subsets.concat((subsetsSum(remaining,target,partialSum.concat([n]))));
```

To:

```
subsets = subsets.concat((subsetsSum(remaining,target,partialSum.concat([n]))));
```

(You could also just use, `subsets.push(...)`)

Comment: It worked! Do you have any idea of how partialSum became an object? I am really intrigued by it... so strange... thanks a lot!

Comment: @Monique There are all kinds of objects in JS and Array is one of them. See also https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/instanceof

Comment: I see! So my array was converted to an obj possibly while it was interacting with the other functions inside my subsetSum function. Very interesting. Thanks again!

Comment: @Monique the array wasn't converted to an object. Rather, a JavaScript Array *is* a kind of object. Specifically, "the JavaScript Array object is a global object that is used in the construction of arrays; which are high-level, list-like objects." (See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array)